# Show as surely convergence (Borel Cantelli Lemma)

Tags: probability-theory

Let ${X_n}$ be independent r.v. taking values $n^2-1$ and $-1$ with $P(X_n=n^2-1)=1/n^2$ and $P(X_n=-1)=1-\frac{1}{n^2}$. Show that if $S_k=X_1+...+X_k$ then $S_k/k$ converges to -1 a.s but $E(S_k)=0$.

Attempt: I can see that $P(\{X_n = n^2 -1\}i.o.)=0$ as the sum $1/n^2$ is finite. After this how to proceed? What do I do with $P(X_n=-1)=1-\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: Compute $E(S_k) = E(X_1)+\dots+E(X_k)$.

Comment: Is E(X_k) = 0 for all k?

Comment: From the definition, it should be easy to compute $E(X_k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A_n\, i.o.$ is identical to $\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty} A_n$. 
Let $A_n:= \{\omega : X_n(\omega) = n^2-1\}$. Then, $P(\liminf\limits_{n\to \infty} A_n^c) = 1- P(A_n \,i.o.) = 1$.

For (a.a.) $\omega \in \liminf\limits_{n\to \infty} A_n^c$, by definition there exists $N=N(\omega)$ s.d. $\forall n\geq N$, $X_n(\omega) = -1$. Hence, $X_n(\omega) \to -1$. Now it's just real analysis and a classic result of Cesaro sum that if a sequence $a_n \to a$, then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i /n \to a$.

It suffices to show $E(X_n) = 0$. In that endeavor, $E(X_n) = (n^2-1) \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} - (1-\frac{1}{n^2}) = 0$. Then $E(S_k) = \frac{1}{k} \sum\limits_{i=1}^k E(X_i) = 0$.

Comment: And the E(S_k) part? It seems simple but I do not see it.